# TrackIR technical issue (stutters)

Tags: simulation

I just aqcuired the TrackIR5 and ProClip to use for my simulation rig, after having used some free alternatives before (using webcam).

I was really looking forward to the increased accuracy as advertised and yes it certainly is responsive, but i have a problem.

It will stutter slightly at random intervals when panning around, in just about any sim i've tried, some being Assetto Corsa, ETS2, DCS, IL2, Elite: Dangerous...

I run all of these at 60fps VSync and it is really smooth with mouselook, but using the trackir i can see short stutters now and then when panning in ALL these titles. So i am suspecting it may be some kind of configuration issue.

Looking at the TrackIR application i can see that all three dots are tracked and no light bleed is occuring. Camera FPS is 119.9 to 120 FPS constantly looking at the camera information screen.

I am using the latest TrackIR 5.3 software with TrackIR5 and ProClip on Windows 10 x64 and i have tried having the clip and cam on different USB ports, to no avail. Also tried raising the process priority to High for trackir. No result.

Is there a known issue with VSync 60fps and trackir? Like it misses frames now and then? Or is it any known issues i should know regarding Win10 and/or 64bit?

It is really smooth and nice most of the time, then it skips frames in rendering (but framerate in game is still 60 locked) all of a sudden when looking around.